# bootstrap.js form script manager not triggering jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, nuget

I have been trying to run jquery validation in my website website.

I have all scripts required scripts through nuget bootstrap and the jquery package.

I have a masterpage and validation is supposed to get triggered on the content page.

List of Scripts that have been triggering from the masterpage:

```
<%--Framework Scripts--%>
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="formValidation" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
    <%--Unify Site Scripts--%>
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="backtotop" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="smoothscroll" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="owlcarousel" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="greensock" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="transitions" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="layerslider" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="app" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="SerialScroll-min" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="ScrollTo-min" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="layer-slider" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="owl-carousel" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="owl-recent-works" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery-easing-pack" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery-easing-compatibility" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery-lavalamp" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery-colors" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="colors" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="colorpicker" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="blipitpicker" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="codaslider" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="maps" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="gmap" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery-form-min" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="page_contacts" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrapValidator" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="mycustom" />
</Scripts>
<script src="Content2/formValidation.js"></script>
<script src="Content2/formValidation.css"></script>
```

I added these above scripts on the masterpage and they are working fine.

My issue is that bootstrap.js is not working through script manager on the jquery validation, plus it's working perfectly fine on other pages, and when I call a new  `<script src="/Content2/bootstrap.js"></script>`
the validation has started working now.

I don't want to use another bootstrap.js on my page - I can't afford to be use two bootstrap.js instances since bootstrap.js is intrinsic to the project I want to know why it is not triggering asp.net webform,sriptmanager or jquery?

Comment: I've separated out the various points of this question so they can be read more easily and fixed some typos.

Comment: You have to reference the bootstrap unobtrusive js file.  Should be called something like jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: jacob roberts i added teh jquery.unobstrusive but still no change please help me out this is client prior requirement to have jquery validator